# How do you print the days until a deadline from the command line?

Tags: bash, date

I have an upcoming deadline on Nov. 1st, 2011, and I want to print the days until the deadline every time I open Terminal on my MacBook Pro.  I've added this to my `.profile`:

```
python -c "from datetime import date; print '%s days until deadline.' % (date(2011,11,1) - date.today()).days"
```

And this prints `146 days until deadline.` whenever I create a new Terminal window.

This solves my need, but I'm wondering what the one-liner looks like in other languages, or if there are ways to use bash or standard posix command line tools to do the same task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo $(expr '(' $(date -d 2011/11/1 +%s) - $(date +%s) + 86399 ')' / 86400) " days until deadline"
```

Comment: For OS X's (BSD's) `date`, I used `echo $(expr '(' $(date -j 11012011 +%s) - $(date +%s) + 86399 ')' / 86400) " days until deadline"`.  It runs about twice as fast as the Python version (0.017s vs 0.037s).

Comment: On OS X, it should be `echo $(expr '(' $(date -jf %m%d%Y 11012011 +%s) - $(date +%s) + 86399 ')' / 86400) " days until deadline"`. The default format will interpret `11012011` as Nov 11, 8:11pm of the current year.

Answer (score 4):

Using awk you can do:

```
echo "2011 11 01" | awk '{dt=mktime($0 " 00 00 00")-systime(); print int(dt/86400) " days";}'
```

#### OUTPUT (as of 8th June 2011)

```
145 days
```

#### Update (to get time difference rounded use below code)

```
awk '{dt=mktime($0 " 00 00 00")-systime(); d=dt/86400+0.5; printf("%d\n",d);}'
```

Comment: I guess it depends if OP wants ceil or round or full # of days irrespective of the fraction time difference value.

Comment: For OS X, I need to use `gawk` instead of `awk`, to get GNU awk and the `mktime` function.  It runs about twice as fast as the Python version (0.019s vs 0.037s).

Comment: Generally, when you count some interval in 'days', you want it click over at midnight, not at noon or any other time.  So rounding doesn't really enter into it.